# Access location variable from another method

Tags: java, android

I want to access the latitude and longitude variables from `onLocationChanged` method in my `test()` method.

```
class MainActivity
{
private IALocationManager mIALocationManager;
Double lat;
Double lng;
private IALocationListener mLocationListener = new IALocationListenerSupport()
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(IALocation location)
    {

         lat = location.getLatitude();
         lng = location.getLongitude();
         Log.d(TAG, "location is: " + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
    }
}

public void test()
{
            Log.d(TAG, "Latitude = " + lat);
            Log.d(TAG, "Longitude = "+ lng);
}
}
```

From the code above, I get the output as

```
//From onLocationChanged
location is: 2.8081944950315636,101.75935307113596
//From test()
Latitude = null 
Longitude = null
```

I can get the location in `onLocationChanged` method but the variable won't store to the `lat` and `lng` and also can't call by `test()` method.
May I know how to solve this problem? Is it possible to pass variable from one method to another method?

Comment: I would guess that `onLocationChanged` is not being fired

Comment: check whether you're getting location or not.

Comment: I've updated my codes, I can get the location from `onLocationChanged` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the variables `lat` Latitude and `lng` Longitude are assigned variable only when `onLocationChanged` is called. So if you call your `test()` method before `onLocationChanged` is called then the values of `lat` and `lng` are not yet assigned and have no value.
 So the solution is call the method `test()` within `onLocationChanged` or check for `null` using an `if` statement to before calling the method!

Comment: Thanks! I called the method `test()` within `onLocationChanged` and `lat` `lng` are having variable now!

Comment: Now I've another problem which is to pass the variable of `lat` `lng` to another activity.... How do I do that? @Xenolion

Comment: Oh for that case I will have to ask you something first, Do you want to go to the next activity just when the location is changed or when a certain button is clicked???

Comment: Since the `onLocationChanged` will keep updating, I want to pass the last updated `lat` `lng` to next activity when certain button is clicked.

Comment: I have got you now. Just ask another question and post the link here due to lack of formatting in comments. But in short is design a button and onlick of the button make sure you put an if statement inside test method `if(lat!=0){ start activity} else{ Toast to user the location has not changed}`.

Comment: Okay all the best @LyeJiaHow, **Happy Coding!**.

Answer (score 0):

Check your onLocationChanged method this must be not triggered, use breakpoints onLocationChanged to see whether your are getting these values or not. If this method is not called then check this must be a delegation issue of Location Class/API.